# Sales, Taxes and Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, finance

I'm working to get some practice with SQL functions which are often used in a financial setting, and I created this simple table with products, prices and tax rates basically.

I then wrote a query to simulate a purchase invoice type of result set (I realize things like that are most often done at application level, or as a separate DB transaction).

After I wrote this query, I found myself using so many parentheses for operations, and repeating the same formulas over and over, and I thought; there's got to be a better way to do this! So here I am seeking peer review.

You can try it **[using SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/338872)**.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sales (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
  , Product NVARCHAR(MAX)
  , Price DECIMAL(6,2)
  , Qty INT
  , Import BIT
  , SalesTaxRate DECIMAL(6,2)
  , ImportTaxRate DECIMAL(6,2)
); 
GO

INSERT INTO #Sales (Product, Price, Qty, Import, SalesTaxRate, ImportTaxRate)
VALUES
  ('Apple Pie',          3.99,  10, 0, 7.50, NULL)
, ('Swiss Chocolate',    6.99,  5,  1, NULL, 5.50)
, ('French Wine',        12.99, 3,  1, 7.50, 5.50)
, ('Complimentary Gift', NULL,  1,  0, NULL, NULL)
; 
GO
```

And here is the query which results in this table being returned:

[image: table]

```
SELECT
  Id
, Product
, [Price] = COALESCE(Price, 0)
, Qty
, [Subtotal] = (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)
, [Sales Tax] = CAST((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))
, [Import Tax] = CAST((ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))
, [Total Tax] = COALESCE(
    CAST(((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)) + (ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty))) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))
    , 0)
, [Line Total] = (
    ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty -- Subtotal
    + COALESCE(
    CAST(((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)) + (ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty))) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))
    , 0)) -- Total Tax
FROM #Sales

UNION

SELECT
  NULL
, 'Totals'
, NULL
, NULL
, SUM((ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)) -- Subtotal
, SUM(CAST((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
, SUM(CAST((ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
, SUM(COALESCE(
    CAST(((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)) + (ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty))) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))
    , 0))
, SUM(
    ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty -- Subtotal
    + COALESCE(
      CAST(((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)) + (ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * (ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty))) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))
      , 0)) -- Total Tax
FROM #Sales
```

Comment: I wish more people included scripts to create sample data. ++

Comment: Is the `#Sales` table supposed to represent one completed transaction? If there are more transactions, then wouldn't you have to create more tables?

Comment: @200_success In my micro-example data, yes, it would represent one completed transaction. In a more complete setting, there would be more tables involved of course (transactions, products, customers, etc.), perhaps this would be more like a view representing one transaction. I perhaps should have included a TransactionId to make that more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Don't Repeat Yourself

Okay, a good way of getting rid of repeated formulas is to use move them into a [`CROSS APPLY`](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained).

We can move the following into a `CROSS APPLY`, which I named `Calcs`.

```
, SUM((ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty)) -- Subtotal
, SUM(CAST((ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
, SUM(CAST((ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
```

I'm actually not going to include the divide by 100 bit in my `CROSS APPLY`, which makes stuff a little easier for us later.

## Applying Yourself to the Problem

For now I'm going to ignore the Totals bit, you'll see why a little later.
This is what the query looks like now:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Product,
    [Price] = COALESCE(Price,0),
    Qty,
    [Subtotal] = Calcs.Item_Price,
    [Sales Tax] = CAST(Calcs.Sales_Tax / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)),
    [Import Tax] = CAST(Calcs.Import_Tax / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)),
    [Total Tax] = COALESCE(CAST((Calcs.Sales_Tax + Calcs.Import_Tax) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)),0),
    [Line Total] = 
    Calcs.Item_Price
    + COALESCE(CAST((Calcs.Sales_Tax + Calcs.Import_Tax) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)),0)
FROM #Sales
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty AS Item_Price,
        (ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) AS Sales_Tax,
        (ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) AS Import_Tax
) Calcs
```

## Rollup, Rollup!

Now, a SQL keyword you don't see used very often. We are going to use [`GROUP BY X WITH ROLLUP`](http://sqlandme.com/2011/07/07/sql-server-tsql-group-by-with-rollup/) to automatically generate a total column for us.

What you want to do is add a `GROUP BY Product WITH ROLLUP` below the `CROSS APPLY`. The query needs a couple of modifications now though, because we've added aggregation.

Basically for anything that will be included in both the data and the totals, you take either the `SUM`, if it is a numeric column, or either the `MIN` or `MAX` for text fields.

For fields that you only want to include in either the data or totals, you have to add a `CASE` statement to the select query similar to one of the following:

```
--For the total column, GROUPING(Product) will be 1
-- for the data columns it will be equal to 0
CASE 
    WHEN GROUPING(Product) = 0 
    THEN MAX(Product) --For data rows, return the product
    ELSE 'Totals' --For the total row, return the text 'Totals'
END AS Product,

CASE 
    WHEN GROUPING(Product) = 0 
    THEN MAX(Price) --For data rows, return the price
    --We don't include an else because we don't want to 
    -- want anything to be returned for this field in the totals column.
END AS Price,
```

## All Together Now!

[Here is what I ended up with](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/340439), which I think has much less repeated formulas and avoids having to basically repeat the entire query twice.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(Product) = 0 
        THEN MAX(Id)
    END AS Id,
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(Product) = 0 
        THEN MAX(Product)
        ELSE 'Totals'
    END AS Product,
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(Product) = 0 
        THEN ISNULL(MAX(Price), 0)
    END AS Price,
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(Product) = 0 
        THEN MAX(Qty)
    END AS Qty,
    [Subtotal] = SUM(Calcs.Item_Price),
    [Sales Tax] = SUM(CAST(Calcs.Sales_Tax / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))),
    [Import Tax] = SUM(CAST(Calcs.Import_Tax / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2))),
    [Total Tax] = SUM(COALESCE(CAST((Calcs.Sales_Tax + Calcs.Import_Tax) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)),0)),
    [Line Total] = 
    SUM(Calcs.Item_Price
    + COALESCE(CAST((Calcs.Sales_Tax + Calcs.Import_Tax) / 100 AS DECIMAL(6,2)),0))
FROM #Sales
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty AS Item_Price,
        (ISNULL(SalesTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) AS Sales_Tax,
        (ISNULL(ImportTaxRate,0) * ISNULL(Price,0) * Qty) AS Import_Tax
) Calcs
GROUP BY Product WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY GROUPING(Product),Id
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks so much, learned a lot from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend specifying an `ORDER BY` clause, even if the ordering is based on something arbitrary like the `Id`.  When users print the same invoice twice, they expect the output to be repeatable.

You used both `COALESCE(Price, 0)` and `ISNULL(Price,0)` — consistency would be good.  I recommend putting a `NOT NULL` constraint on `Price` — perhaps also with `DEFAULT 0.00`.

Be careful about doing the same on the tax column, though!  Canadian GST makes a distinction between [untaxable items and items taxed at 0%](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/menu-eng.html).  For that reason, I believe that a `NULL` tax rate should be propagated when multiplying, and only treated as 0.00 for the summation.

Comment: Good points. Taxes are fun, aren't they?